# leaves (together) with the other/others

Tags: grammar

The men head out except for Tony who goes to the large TV.

The men: Hey Tony, are you coming?

Tony takes the TV and leaves together with the other(s)

1. Just to be sure, "others" is correct here isn't it?
2. Also, could I leave out "together"?

Comment: 1. Yes, 2. Yes.

Answer (score 0):

| Sentence | Correctness |
| --- | --- |
| Tony took the TV and left together with the ***others*** | good |
| Tony took the TV and left together with the ***other*** | bad |
| Tony took the TV and left together with the ***other*** men | good |

There is more than one man, so you can use "others" with an "s" at the end of the word.

The word "other" is usually used as an adjective. The word "other" is usually followed by a noun. You can write, "the other ***hand***" or "the other ***door***". So, you would write, "Tony left with the **other men**" instead of "Tony left with the **other**"

---

You asked if you could leave out the word "together". The answer is: Yes you can.

| Sentence | Correctness |
| --- | --- |
| Tony took the TV and left **together** with the others | correct/good |
| Tony took the TV and left with the others | correct/good |

Usually, stories like this would be written in the past-tense instead of being written in the present-tense.

> The men began to head out, except for Tony. Tony went over to the large TV.
>
> The men asked, "Hey Tony, are you coming?
>
> Tony took the TV and left together with the other(s)

It sounds like a robbery or burglary. I hope that you study happier examples in the future.